# How to get a heading to scale with a image and keep spacing ratio html/css

Tags: html, image, css, spacing

I would like to have a image on the left with a heading on the right. I want both of them to scale in size and spacing as the page is shrunk. I have used this code: `width: 10%; height: auto; margin: 2% 0px;` to have the image on the top left of my page and scale in both spacing and size to the page when the browser is shrunk (I have also included media queries which wouldn't think would make a difference). I have tried using `positioning: absolute` which doesn't work. I am a novice to using HTML5 and CSS3. This is my first project and second post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That should be `position: absolute`, not `positioning`. But you should post the code you've tried and explain what's going wrong - it will greatly help anyone to help you out.

Comment: I have tried using viewports but don't fully understand how they work. When I use them, the text starts off too big and then shrinks too small. I can't get the ratio right. Edit: Also tried using 'float: left;' on the image and that sorts part of the problem out, now all I need to know is how so fix the size and spacing ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do
HTML

```
 <div class="wrapper"><img src="yourimage.jpg"/><h1>my Heading Goes here</h1></div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrapper {
   width: 100%; 
   height: auto; 
   max-width: 600px; 
   border: thin solid #333;
 }
div.wrapper:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   clear: both;
}
div.wrapper img {
   display: block; 
   float: left; width: 40%; 
   height: auto; 
   margin-right: 5%;
}
div.h1 {
   display: inline-block;
   line-height: 20px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

You can check it here
[jsfidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ffcnnxn/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you make a http://jsfiddle.net/? 
It's kinda hard to understand what you're after based on our description alone.

Comment: If you have the images hosted on your site you can use a direct link; e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/2evafkga/, otherwise just use an empty img src with alt="placeholder image" or something along those lines. :) *Edit: Or, can you provide a link to your site if it is online?